# ReactiveCocoa simple property binding with swift

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to do some simple model - view model binding with ReactiveCocoa using swift

The Workflow:

My model loads some data (categories in this case) and updates its loadingCategories state. true if loading, false if not

Then in my view model I want it to bind its own loading property to the loadingCategories property in the model

Here's the code. It doesn't work. The only examples I could find out there was using signals for UIControls, and I couldn't figure out how to use those examples for property binding (no controls)

```
let loading = self.categorySelector.rac_valuesAndChangesForKeyPath("loadingCategories", options: .New, observer: nil)
loading.subscribeNextAs { (l:Bool) -> () in
  self.loading = l;
}
```

When run I just get an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.

Comment: what is the unrecognized selector and what object is receiving it? This should be printed in your debugger when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observer parameter cannot be nil, it should be the object sending the signal on property change (self.categorySelector)

```
let loading = self.categorySelector.rac_valuesForKeyPath("loadingCategories",  observer:self.categorySelector)
loading.subscribeNextAs { 
   [weak self] (l:Bool) -> () in
   if (self != nil){
       self!.loading = l;
   }
}
```

make sure to not retain the ownership on self in the closure by specifying "unowned" otherwise you will have a retain cycle causing memory leak.

Last but not least make sure your observed property is annoted dynamic:

```
dynamic var loadingCategories:Bool!
```